# SQL Apex new table from two other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid which is based on a table:

```
select A, B, C from "TABLE_X"
```

Now I have a modal dialog where the user could enter

> Name 
> Email Address

Now I would like to combine both tables after a button is pressed and write the information into a new table which should look like this:

```
Table Y:
A   B   C   Name   Email
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are "both tables"?  Is there a second table where the modal dialog has written the data that you want to join to?  Or do you just want to include the modal dialog's page item values in your `insert` statement?  How do you know which row(s) from `table_x` the modal dialog's page item values relate to (or do you want the same `name` and `email` in every row of `table_y`?

Comment: The page items of the modal page are not stored inside a table, I basically would like to include the data into the insert statement. The data is currently not connected, I don't know how to add and identifier. Or to store the data in two tables and connect them somehow.

Comment: You can include the page items from the modal page in your `insert` statement just like you would include page items from the current page.  If you don't have a way to connect the page items to a particular row from the interactive grid and you want to tie the name and email to a particular row, presumably you'd need an additional (likely hidden) item has the `table_x` key that is populated when the modal dialog is opened.

Comment: I see thanks for your comments. How to automatically populate that key, when the dialog is open? This is not clear to me.

Comment: That depends on how the dialog is being opened.  I would guess that you know which row(s) you want to associate the `name` and `email` with when you open the modal dialog and that you'd want to pass that information to the modal dialog when you open it.

Comment: I have created a unique key with SELECT sys_guid() from DUAL but I would like to insert one and the same key into all rows of the current session in order to link the key to the second table.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means exactly.  Did you create a trigger on `table_x` that populates the primary key column?  Assuming that is what you mean, presumably that GUID is selected as part of your interactive report.  When you open the modal dialog to enter the `name` and `email` that are supposed to relate to a particular row, you'd pass that GUID as a parameter to the modal dialog.

Comment: Yes, this works the problem is that the key is unique for each id. I need the same ID inside the interactive report for each row in order to connect it with email and name single row. The table_x is deleted after sessions ends.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  What is the "key" and the "id" in this context?  What do you mean "same ID ... for each row"?  So every row in `table_x` has the same `id` value?  I believe you previously said that you were going to link the `name` and `email` to a particular row in `table_x` not every row.  Does `table_x` have both a numeric primary key `id` and a separate, unique GUID column?  That would be odd.  If you want to preserve both then you'd want to have two hidden items, not just one, in the modal dialog page and pass both as parameters.